# Can anyone tell me what this tool is?

Tags: tools, measuring, chainsaw

[image]

I work for the Forest service and this strange tool just showed up. Can't figure out what it is. Maybe a saw chain measuring tool or tree sight?,

Comment: Have you tried the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20230000000000*/http://crew13.com/)?

Comment: Could be a flat spanner wrench, or size gauge. The "K+" looks like part of the imprint of Keuffel & Esser, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keuffel_and_Esser, who made drafting tools. Perhaps a wrench for a pantograph? Adjustment tool for bike shock absorber?? "CREW13.COM" appears to be a dead end,

Comment: Crew13 made custom fire fighting equipment. Their web site (thanks @HABO) was very sparse, mainly "email me".  Looks likely to be a gage, like a caliper for two standard measurements.  What do you fabricate to that size in your work?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a fuel sizing gauge...

[image]

https://www.forestry-suppliers.com/p/89012/86871/wildland-fire-fuel-sizing-gauge

Answer (score 0):

Crew13.com seems to have been involved in wilderness fire-fighting eqiupment and "K+" is their logo, or possibly the logo of Kristofer

https://web.archive.org/web/20180806082253/http://crew13.com/

[image]